# Three.js camera position caught in if else statement

Tags: javascript, three.js

Trying to add more variability to camera position to make the 3D scene more interesting. So I made an if else statement but the camera starts getting caught at -12, where it oscillates up and down between 12.00 and 12.05 before finally getting out. I want to increment camera.position.z back to 30 once it hits -12. How can I do that without getting trapped at -12?

```
camera.position.set(0, -8, 30);

function render() {
                time += 0.1;
                requestAnimationFrame(render);


                if (camera.position.z > 20) {
                    camera.position.z -= 0.1;
                    camera.position.y += 0.1;
                }
                else if (camera.position.z <= 20 && camera.position.z >= -12){
                    camera.position.z -= 0.1;
                }
                else {camera.position.z = 30}
}
```

Comment: please check your last else condition you added == sign there.. `else {camera.position.z == 30}`  replace it with `else {camera.position.z = 30}`

Comment: Ok fixed, but how would I increment it back up to 30 without it getting trapped at -12?

Comment: can you create jsfeddle link... so that it would be easy for me to solve your problem ;-)

Comment: why wouldn't to use a chain of tweenings (`tween.js`) for your camera movement?

Answer (score 0):

`==` is the equality operator, not the assignment operator. For assignment, use `=` instead. In you last else clause, you wrote

```
else {camera.position.z == 30}
```

... instead write

```
else {camera.position.z = 30}
```

Comment: Ok fixed, but how would I increment it back up to 30 without it getting trapped at -12?